# canShowBlock() returning false in simple product search

Tags: php, css, magento

Our product search is currently showing up in a weird manner and I think I have figured out why, but can't work out how to rectify it.

In catalogue/layer/view.phtml one of the first lines states:

```
<?php if($this->canShowBlock()): ?>
<div class="side-col float_l block block-layered-nav">
```

and looking at the div class, I can see that in the normal product list, the div with all the filtering options has these classes, but in the search function it has:

```
<div style="display:none" class="amshopby-overlay"></div>
```

So it seems that for some reason canShowBlock() is returning false.  This is what that function does:

```
public function canShowBlock()
{
    if ($this->canShowOptions())
        return true;

    $cnt = 0;
    $pos = Mage::getStoreConfig('amshopby/block/state_pos'); 
    if (!$this->_notInBlock($pos)){
        $cnt = count($this->getLayer()->getState()->getFilters());
    }        
    return $cnt;
}
```

and I have looked through it, checked various attributes to make sure there are ones enabled properly to work with the search, but it is still not working... any ideas?  [Here is how the page is displaying](http://www.urbanrider.co.uk/catalogsearch/result/?q=tucano%20urbano).

Comment: `$this->_notInBlock($pos)` returns true? need more details. BTW I'm not visiting your site!

Comment: Possible interesting datapoint: It looks like you've got an extension from "Amasty" installed, and this extension isn't 100% compatible with your theme.

Comment: @Waygood haha sorry, wasn't trying to increase hits or anything, heres a [screenshot of how it looks](http://i.imgur.com/CfGKJz2.jpg)

Comment: @AlanStorm interesting, thanks, will look into this, where can I find more information?

Comment: @Waygood To be honest I'm not sure if $this->canShowOptions() returns false or if $this->_notInBlock($pos) returns true, what would be the best way of testing?